# How to execute Maven plugins dynamically?

Tags: maven-3, maven-lifecycle

I am using `maven-remote-resources-plugin`, which retrieves the remote resources (such as css file) from another project to a specific directory in the current project. Since I am developing the css files, I would really like to see the changes in runtime with a simple reload-page click on the browser, instead of recompiling and rebuilding the maven project.

My first thought is to remove the `build` tags wrapping around the plugins, which didn't work.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>      
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
```

How can I achieve this? First post -- thanks very much to all so-ers!